# How to simultaneously process 2 FASTA generators

Tags: python

This seems so trivial, yet its giving me a hard time. I would simply like to process two fasta generators at the same time so as to compare the first header and sequence of one file with the first header and sequence of another file, the second to the second, and so on until both files are complete.

Both fasta files have the same number of sequences, and they are ordered as 2 reads of a pair e.g. the first sequence of fasta1 and the first sequence of fasta 2 are read pairs and so on til the end of the files.

I have a generator that gives me the header and sequence for each sequence of a fasta file

```
def fileParse (self):
    # get file from __init__ and open.
    # parse header and sequence
    yield (header, sequence)
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over two files at the same time. I started with this:

```
# x class variable sends first fasta
# y class variable sends second fasta 
for header, sequence in x.fileParse():
    for header2, sequence2 in y.fileParse():
        # compare headers and evaluate.
```

Obvsiously the problem here is that I compare each header in one file to each header in another, where I only want to compare the first header to the first header, the second to the second, and so on.

I am having difficulty cause it seems as if I always need to iterate through the generator. Maybe I need to adjust the genrator method itself to generate a header and sequence for two files simultaneously?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is what you're looking for:

```
for (h1, s1), (h2, s2) in zip(x.fileParse(), y.fileParse()):
```

IMHO, `zip` is easiest to understand by an example:

```
In [43]: range(5)
Out[43]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [44]: range(3,8)
Out[44]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [45]: zip(range(5), range(3,8))
Out[45]: [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
```

P.S. It's implied by your question that you're implementing a fasta reader yourself. If that's the case, you might want to take a look at BioPython's [SeqIO](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Zip() is quite a handy method. And regarding the SeqIO I could just as easily implement that but I figure it will also provide me with 2 generators. Thank you!